# Jumping into an if block

Tags: vb6

So I'm maintaining some legacy code, in which there is a GoTo leading right before the End If of an if block. My predicament is that I now need to add an Else clause to that block. Will the Else function correctly if it is reached via the GoTo rather than failing the If?

Comment: Sounds ugly as sin, but yes... why wouldn't it?

Comment: I have no idea, I've always been taught to avoid GoTo like the plague, so I have no idea how it works. Im not sure if the if stays in scope or not, or whatever else takes place behind the scenees

Comment: Try it and let us know how it turns out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GoTo` is completely unstructured, and will continue execution wherever you tell it to, regardless of the block of code that it takes you to. If you need the `Else` condition to execute based on a change in the parameters that happens after your `If` test but before the `GoTo`, it won't work.  If you don't care how the `If` statement is evaluated, it *may* work, but this would be an ideal time to fix the underlying control flow issue.  You can see this behavior with the following sample code by stepping through it with the debugger:

```
Private Sub DontTryThisAtHome()
    Dim test As Long
    Dim doneThat As Boolean

    If test = 0 Then
        Debug.Print "If condition tested."
Spaghetti:
        Debug.Print "This always executes even if test = " & test & "."
        If doneThat Then GoTo Pasta
    Else
        Debug.Print "test > 0"
    End If

    test = 1
    doneThat = True
    Debug.Print "Pasta express..."
    GoTo Spaghetti
Pasta:
End Sub
```

Output:

```
If condition tested.
This always executes even if test = 0.
Pasta express...
This always executes even if test = 1.
```

Answer (score 2):

**Just don't do it.**

Legacy code is hard enough to understand, even without the previous guy taking advantage of some language dark corner. Don't make life confusing for the next guy.

Rewrite the code in question so it is clean and obvious.